# Match characters within a special character

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract names included in `%` signs from a string. For example `"%column1%` is the first column and `%column2%` is the second one, and `%column'-4%` is a column with characters other than Work"

Is there a way to extract the column names from the phrase above?

Comment: Could you use `\%` to match the markers?

Comment: Yes of course there is. Have you tried anything? What language are you working in?

Comment: I'm sorry, I write in c# it almost works with "%\\w*%" but it breaks as soon as there's e.g. ' (apostrophy) character between the percentages.

Comment: Jeez, people are nervous these days. What's the point in down voting? Ignore the question if you think it's stupid, not everyone in is a Regex guru.

Comment: People are generally not voting down because of the stupidity of a question. Bad questions get down voted. For instance: your title could be improved (e.g. How to find delimited tokens from a phrase). and the question can use some improved as well (e.g. Make clear that "%column1% … than Work" is a phrase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `%(.+?)%`, and use your programming language to specify the Regex global option (commonly `/g`), and get all of the matches back. Each match will contain `column1`, `column2`, etc.

Comment: No, the matches will also contain the `%`s? The capturing groups will contain only the names.

Comment: it's fine, I can get rid of %s with trimstart("%").trimEnd("%"). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match them:

```
(?<=%).*?(?=%)
```

Use your application language (unspecified) to extract them.

If your application language doesn't support look arounds, use group 1 from this regex:

```
%(.*?)%
```

Comment: Why so complicated? His language might not support lookahead/lookbehind. Why not just `/%(.+?)%/g` ? Also, you're missing a capture group - in some implementations a capture group is required if you're going to capture any data.

Comment: @SpikeX his language might not have the `g` modifier :p

Comment: @HamZa I'm pretty sure it's way more common to have the global flag than to have lookahead/lookbehind, but yes, I suppose you're technically correct. :P

Comment: @SpikeX is that better? Note that some situations require (or is far simpler if) the whole match to be your target, eg java's `replaceAll()`